# Find text boundaries in PDF with many texts

Tags: pdf, computer-vision, pattern-matching, deep-learning, text-mining

I have a set (300k) of PDFs with multiple-choice questions (about 50 per PDF).

Each of this PDF may have a slight different layout, which makes it impossible to just convert to text (pdftotext) and match using REGEXP.

> Question 1
>
> WORDING
>
> a) ALTERNATIVE_A
>
> b) ALTERNATIVE_B
>
> c) ALTERNATIVE_C
>
> d) ALTERNATIVE_D

.

> Q1) WORDING
>
> a. ALTERNATIVE_A
>
> b. ALTERNATIVE_B
>
> c. ALTERNATIVE_C
>
> d. ALTERNATIVE_D
>
> e. ALTERNATIVE_E

On the other hand, all files have in common that its questions are near to its alternativas and far from other questions. This characteristic made me wonder if this is a computer vision task.

[image: Questions and alternatives]

Is there any software which could aid me in this task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem in getting the text or locating the questions?

If it is the former your problem can be solved using an OCR (Optical Character Recognition) software. Specifically you should look for one that works on PDFs such as this one:
http://www.onlineocr.net/

This could (if works properly) give you the text in the pdf which you could farther parse using

If your problem is locating the questions I would expect NLP techniques will work better than visual ones, but if you really want to do it using computer vision then I would suggest looking into bounding box detection/suggestion algorithms.